# Regular expression pattern not working correctly in VB.NET

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, winforms

**Short Version: I am trying to build the regular expression to find out if a string contains "0,0,0,0". Every attempt I have made only returns each character as a match, not the full string within the quotes.**

I am trying to find certain text within a string inside of a textbox in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). My issue is that instead of returning one match it is returning each character within the string as a match. Now normally I would figure it is an issue with my regular expression, but since I have verified it should work with a couple of online tools, I am not 100% sure.

The string I am trying to match is:

```
0,0,0,0
```

The string I am trying to find the match in would look like this:

```
Image(0,0,0,0,"Path")
```

I am using a control called FastColoredTextBox, and it allows to set ranges for color styling and other custom styles for specific strings. Below is how I usually add style ranges.

Currently, I have added the ability to make words clickable, so I am trying to get the regular expression to build matches for the strings I want to make clickable. For example:

Here is the regular expression.

```
Private Sub tb_textchanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)

    ' This is working code to make the word Path clickable in the above string:
    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(ellipseStyle, "\bPath\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    ' When I use these ones it returns each character as a match and not the full string. The mystery...
    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(ellipseStyle, "0,0,0,0", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    e.ChangedRange.SetStyle(ellipseStyle, "(0,){4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
End Sub
```

When the user clicks the words that are set as a range using regular expression (example of this above), it makes the words clickable. When the user clicks the word it then selects the whole range specified in the regular expression. Except this one is returning each "0" and "," as its own match thus only returning/selecting single characters.

Here is my code to click the word for a better understanding. This does not contain the regular expression, the above textchanged event does.

```
Private Sub tb_VisualMarkerClick(sender As Object, e As VisualMarkerEventArgs)
    Dim page As RadPageViewPage = RadPageView1.SelectedPage
    Dim txt As FastColoredTextBox = TryCast(page.Controls(0), FastColoredTextBox)
    txt.Invalidate()
    txt.Selection.Start = New Place((TryCast(e.Marker, RangeMarker).range).Start.iChar, (TryCast(e.Marker, RangeMarker).range).Start.iLine)
    txt.SelectionLength = (TryCast(e.Marker, RangeMarker).range).Text.Length
    Dim ClickedWord As String = (TryCast(e.Marker, RangeMarker).range.Text)
    If ClickedWord = "Path" Then
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.FileName = ""
        ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg)|*.bmp;*.jpg"
        If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

            txt.InsertText(ofd.FileName)
        End If
    ElseIf ClickedWord = "0,0,0,0" Then
        'What I am going to do when found.
    End If
End Sub
```

Sorry for the long winded post, I am just hoping for someone to help me solve my mystery.

Comment: Could you add a question mark, its hard to see what you're actually asking.

Comment: Where's the RegEx? I know you feel like the RegEx is right, but if it's matching individual characters rather than the entire string, it's almost certainly the RegEx.

Comment: I know where you are coming from Michael, that is exactly what I thought. I have tried Vjays regex aswell and I am getting single characters aswell. Can you suggest regex to find see if the string contains 0,0,0,0?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting how you are using `RegEx` in the code block you provided. Try the below syntax (it's in C#).

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split("Input string", "([0.]+)")
```

Comment: The regex is not in the code block it is in the snippets I added before it. the e.changedrange.setstyle. Those snippets are in my textchanged event.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I tried your regex in my code and it is returning each 0 in the string.

Comment: Can you give me the input string your passing.As i tried with "0.0.0.0.somthing".Its returning "0.0.0.0"

Comment: This is the string I am looking to find within the full text."0,0,0,0" Those are commas.

Comment: Trying to see if this: Image(0,0,0,0,"Path") or any other string for that matter contains this: 0,0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

Look into this console application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sPattern = "0,0,0,0";
        string s = "i am looking for  0,0,0,0";

        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
                s, sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", sPattern);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used *[My Regex Tester](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php)*. The code generated is:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim sourcestring As String = "Replace with your source string"
        Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(0,){4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
        Dim mIdx As Integer = 0
        For Each m As Match In mc
            For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", _
                                  mIdx, _
                                  re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), _
                                  m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
            Next
            mIdx = mIdx + 1
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Input text:

```
Image(0,0,0,0,"Path")
```

Output Result:

```
[0][0] = 0,0,0,0,
[0][1] = 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do.

To check if a string contains a pattern e.g. 0,0,0,0, you can use this:

```
string input = "Image(0,0,0,0,\"Path\")";
string pattern = "0,0,0,0";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


Console.WriteLine(input.Contains(pattern)); //true
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch(input)); //true
```